# How to access a gridview column on rowdatabound ?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, rowdatabound

I would like to change the value of my gridview column to active when the value is 1.
I have gridview column like

```
<asp:BoundField   DataField="STATUS" HeaderText="STATUS" SortExpression="STATUS" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></HeaderStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>
```

and cs code

```
 protected void gvCategory_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (e.Row.Cells[5].Text=="0")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[5].Text = "INACTIVE";
            }
        }
    }
```

This is working but it would fail if i change the column order.
What i need is something like findControl function.
Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a few utilities I wrote years ago that may help you:

```
// ---- GetCellByName ----------------------------------
//
// pass in a GridViewRow and a database column name 
// returns a DataControlFieldCell or null

static public DataControlFieldCell GetCellByName(GridViewRow Row, String CellName)
{
    foreach (DataControlFieldCell Cell in Row.Cells)
    {
        if (Cell.ContainingField.ToString() == CellName)
            return Cell;
    }
    return null;
}

// ---- GetColumnIndexByHeaderText ----------------------------------
//
// pass in a GridView and a Column's Header Text
// returns index of the column if found 
// returns -1 if not found 

static public int GetColumnIndexByHeaderText(GridView aGridView, String ColumnText)
{
    TableCell Cell;
    for (int Index = 0; Index < aGridView.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; Index++)
    {
        Cell = aGridView.HeaderRow.Cells[Index];
        if (Cell.Text.ToString() == ColumnText)
            return Index;
    }
    return -1;
}

// ---- GetColumnIndexByDBName ----------------------------------
//
// pass in a GridView and a database field name
// returns index of the bound column if found 
// returns -1 if not found 

static public int GetColumnIndexByDBName(GridView aGridView, String ColumnText)
{
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField DataColumn;

    for (int Index = 0; Index < aGridView.Columns.Count; Index++)
    {
        DataColumn = aGridView.Columns[Index] as System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField;

        if (DataColumn != null)
        {
            if (DataColumn.DataField == ColumnText)
                return Index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: For the first function `GetCellByName`, that should only be called when it's the Header row type: `e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header`

Comment: @DavidFreitas  don't think so.  It uses the underlying DataControlField of a given cell.

Answer (score 3):

You could loop all columns to get the correct index or use this LINQ:

```
String colToFind = "status";
int colIndex = ((GridView)sender).Columns.Cast<DataControlField>()
                .Where((c, index) => c.HeaderText.ToLower().Equals(colToFind))
                .Select((c,index)=>index).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaner easier to read LINQ. Tim's did not work for me.

```
private int GetFirstGridViewColIndex(string dataField, object sender)
{
    var boundFieldColumns = ((GridView)sender).Columns.Cast<BoundField>();

    return boundFieldColumns.Where((column, index) => string.Equals(column.DataField, dataField, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        .Select((column, index) => index)
        .First();
}
```